# Can we pass a basic operator "<" as a callable argument?

Tags: c++, lambda, parameter-passing, operators, callable

My low-level routine needs a argument, to specify it should compare data with LessThan(`<`) or GreatThan(`>`) operator.

Like this:

```
using CompOp_f = std::function<bool( double, double )>;
struct LowLevelObj_t {
    bool doChecking() {
        return _op( _x, _y );
    };

    CompOp_f _op;
    double   _x;
    double   _y;
};
```

When using it, I have to do as following:

```
LowLevelObj_t a {
    ._op = []( double l_, double r_ ) { return l_ < r_; },
    ._x = -1.,
    ._y = 1.,
};

// when I need it with LessThan
bool pos_result = a.doChecking();

// when I need it with GreatThan
a._op = []( double l_, double r_ ) { return l_ > r_; };
bool neg_result = a.doChecking();
```

I want to do it like this:

```
// when I need it with LessThan
a._op = <;
bool pos_result = a.doChecking();

// when I need it with GreatThan
a._op = >;
bool neg_result = a.doChecking();
```

In this way, I can make it not only more readable, but also faster?
Because with using a lambda obj, there are some extra overhead?

Can I do it in any way?

How to get it?

I know I can do it with template syntax, and then specialize LowLevelObj_t with different arguments. But in that way, I have to code `doChecking()` twice, because the real logic is very complex.

Comment: You can't do it like that. There's [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) (and its mates) that you can use.

Comment: *I have to code doChecking() twice, because the real logic is very complex.* -- Seeing is believing.  Why can't you simply change all of your hard-coded comparisons from `<` to a `CompareFunc` function that takes two arguments, and default it to `std::less`?  I would bet that `std::sort`, `std::priority_queue`, etc. has "complex logic", yet they are able to have such a facility.

Comment: `.op = std::less<double>{},` or the `<ranges>` version: `.op = std::ranges::less{},`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thx!  In fact std::less looks like a lambda obj, so it also incurs some overhead?

Comment: @Leon the only overhead is construction of a data-less object, which is practically no overhead at all (same with a *non-capturing* lambda). Using `std::function` itself is more overhead. Have you tried profiling your code yet to see where it spends its time and how much resources it uses, to see if this is actually an issue?